# Thousands of memory leaks when using sbjson framework on repeated usage

Tags: memory, ios4, json-framework

I am using JSON framework (SBJson) for my applicaition.

parsing the value by

```
NSDictionary *results = [responseString JSONValue] ;
```

For parsing first time in controller with this code has no problem. when i call again for same controller it shows thousands of memory leaks.

I went through many forums but in vain. can anybody please tell me what i went wrong?

Full Code:

```
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    //NSDictionary *results =[[response JSONValue] retain] ;

    if (results) {
        [results release];
        results=nil;
    }


    results =[[response JSONValue] retain] ;
    [response release];
```

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Sathish

[image: Leaks in SBJSONValue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try releasing the object before parsing it a second time.

```
[results release];
results = nil;
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply aurum but i inited the nsdictionary and release and nilled it but the problem persisting. whether nsdictionary has to be put "retain" or it has "init"